# ExtJS auto update record

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have several grids where clicking on a row triggers the corresponding record to be bound to a form. If the form is edited, I want the changes to automatically be propagated to the record. The way it works now, If you click on one row in the grid and make some changes in the form and then click on another row, the changes are lost. Even if you click on the same row it re-loads the data and throws out the changes.

I want the user to be able to edit multiple records and then save them all at once.

Edit:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cj9

Click on one of the records, change a field in the form and then click on the record again.

Comment: Can you post the code or create a fiddle for your grid/form interaction so we can see where exactly you are losing your changes?

Comment: You could check if the form is dirty (after clicked on a row and edited the record values) and use the beforeselect event in the grid to push the data back into the previously selected record.